# Python pip3 install Scrapy or Twisted gives"Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-51x6vr4n/Twisted/"

Tags: python, scrapy

I want install scrapy with pip3,

```
sudo pip3 install Scrapy -i https://pypi.douban.com/simple
```

but failed:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-s3504tu6/Twisted/
```

so I used

```
sudo pip3 install Scrapy -i https://pypi.douban.com/simple
```

but it failed again. How to solve this error?

Comment: faild... faild how? do you copy the log? better share it fast or downvotes will come :(

Answer (score -1):

Try upgrading `setuptools`

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

or

```
 easy_install -U setuptools
```

And check if it works